# I'm trying to call function Msg() from function int_err() and int_err() from Msg()

Tags: python-3.x, function, circular-reference

I am writing an Error class (class stuff left out for clarity).  It needs to be able to issue error messages when it is called with bad parameters.  I use a `Msg()` function to hold all the machinery used to process messages (e.g. determine if a message is so severe as to cause termination and to maintain error counts).

```
def Msg(level, text)
    print('level' + '-' + text)
    if level == 'unknown':
        int_err(text)
    # ...
def info(text)
    # ...
    Msg('info', text)
def warn(text)
    # ...
    Msg('warn', text)
# . . .
def int_err(text)
    Msg('internal error', text)
    # ...

info('informational')
warn('warning')
Msg('unknown', 'erroneous call')
```

This fails because `int_err()` is not defined when it is called from `Msg()`.  If I move `def int_err()` above `def Msg()` then `Msg()` is not defined when called from `int_err()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found I can fix the problem by adding `int_err = None` before `def Msg()`, changing the `def int_err()` to `def int_err_prime()`, and following that `def` with `int_err = int_err_prim`e.

```
int_err = None                         #<=====
def Msg(level, text)
    print('level' + '-' + text)
    if level == 'unknown':
        int_err(text)
    # ...
def info(text)
    # ...
    Msg('info', text)
def warn(text)
    # ...
    Msg('warn', text)
# . . .
def int_err_prime(text=None)     #<=====+++ prototype need to be =None
    Msg('internal error', text)
    # ...
int_err = int_err_prime                #<=====
info('informational')
warn('warning')
Msg('unknown', 'erroneous call')
```

Now `int_err` is defined prior to the definition of `Msg()` and contains the correct function address before it is ever called by using `int_err = int_err_prime`.